# How to find mouse position on HTML DOM

Tags: javascript, ajax, fetch-api

I know this question is answered many times, but I have a different scenario.

I have a requirement where on mousehover I need to change source of image, and on mouseout I need to display original image.

The image that I want to change on mouse hover is coming from GET request. Please find pseudo code below:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('img').addEventListener('mouseover',function(event){
var source = event.currentTarget.src;
fetch(url).then(function(data) {
    source.setAttribute('src',data.image);
})
})
```

Now I have multiple image tags on my page, and I want to change source on mouse over.
The problem that I am facing is, on mouse over, I am not getting response immediately as I am doing ajax call. So if I move mouse very quickly from one image to another, response from previous image is getting displayed on current image.
Let me know the solution if any, I know its bit complicated to understand but I really need help on it.

I am thinking of if I can add `if` check (the image on whose hover the call is made and current position of mouse is same) before changing image source.

Comment: From where does come the `url` variable ? And why do you need to fetch ? I think just replacing the `src` attribute of the `img` element should do the trick.

Comment: URL is a service that return an image. I have defined it as part of config.
Yes I am replacing img src attribute only, but because of ajax call it is taking some time.. so previous image source is getting rendered on current image source.

Comment: "URL is a service that return an image". Are you sure ? I would guess that it is the url of an image. Can you confirm ?

Comment: Yes, URL is a service that returns an image. Image url is in data object(data.image).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try something like this

```
var imageChanger = function (elt, url) {
    fetch(url).then(function (data) {
        elt.src = data.image;
    };
}

document.getElementsByTagName('img').addEventListener('mouseover', function (event) {
    imageChanger(event.currentTarget, url);
});
```

Doing so and because you have an asynchronous process, you might have the `mouseleave` event that will trigger before the resolution of the fetch. This will make your image not going back to the previous image.

I will suggest adding something to your code to prevent this.

You could try :

```
var imageChanger = function (elt, url) {
    elt.dataset.original = elt.src;
    elt.dataset.changed = true;

    if (elt.dataset.secondary) {
        elt.src = elt.dataset.secondary;
    } else {
        fetch(url).then(function (data) {
            if (elt.dataset.changed) elt.src = data.image;
            elt.dataset.secondary = data.image;
        }
    }
}

var imageRestore = function (elt) {
    elt.src = elt.dataset.original;
    elt.dataset.changed = false;
}

document.getElementsByTagName('img').addEventListener('mouseleave', function (event) {
    imageRestore (event.currentTarget);
});

document.getElementsByTagName('img').addEventListener('mouseover', function (event) {
    imageChanger(event.currentTarget, url);
});
```

Comment: Thank! I will try it and will get back to you. :)